# PHP and printing out whitespace?

Tags: php

I was wondering how can I print out whitespace in the following code below.

```
<?php echo "$first_name", "$last_name" ; ?>
```

Comment: Let me guess, you come from Python?

Comment: +1, nice comment, Sbm007

Answer (score 3):

Just, well, add whitespace to your output?

```
<?php echo "$first_name $last_name with     some    whitespace" ; ?>
```

Sometimes, it the obvious answer is right - even in PHP!

Comment: I was thinking that, but I was wondering if there was a better way. thanks.

Comment: Except for the fact that most browsers will treat multiple spaces as a single space.  If I really need to display multiple spaces, I normally use an "&nbsp;" or enclose the output in <pre></pre> tags

Answer (score 2):

If you want to concatenate several strings without the double quotes (e.g. when using single quotes):

```
$string = $first_name . ' ' . $last_name; // The dot is a concatenation operator
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
echo "$first_name $last_name"; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when you use `'` any var aren't display, with `"` does.
So, good is:
`<?php echo "$first_name      $last_name" ; ?>`
bad
`<?php echo '$first_name    $last_name' ; ?>`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using commas:

```
<?php echo  $first_name, ' ', $last_name; ?>
```